# How to do media integration with Java

Tags: java, media, desktop

a was thinking if it is possible (probably) or if some framework exists (not-probably) for integrating media controls into Java application. Say I have completed media player in Java (java GStreamer) but with controls directly from Swing. But if I want to stop my player or play next song, I have these media keys on my keyboard, and when I press them, I suppose OS processes them and sends them to corresponding media application. So, I want to ask if you know some framework or library or something that would support this integration on multi platforms (I am aware of possibility to code it in JNI for each platform, but it doesn't seem as pretty solution to me), or if you have some experience with such problem and would provide some advice. I know that java.awt.Desktop exists and I supposed it would support these things when I stumbled on it, but it doesn't.

Thanks for any help, even for trying :)

Comment: It would require natives to hook into the Media Keys of a keyboard, Java does not provide inbuilt support to detect them.  I don't know of any native APIs for that offhand.

Comment: Of course scanning for keys is possible, I just supposed that some API would exist for cleaner access to media control directly from OS.

Comment: Java is not the best choice for anything containing the words *"directly from OS."*